# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS except one page with web.config

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I would like to get all pages redirected from HTTP to HTTPS except one page (pagename.php) in the root directory, this page needs to work as HTTP (needs to be redirected back to HTTP). I currently have the following code to redirect from none-www to www and HTTP to HTTPS.

```html
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true" >
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
              pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

I need other role or exception in this role to rewrite back or redirect  specific URLs to HTTP (There are only 2 URLs I need to get worked as HTTP and they are only the ones with .php page extension and all the other are different).

I would really appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a condition with negate="true" to add the exception for your php files.

```
 <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF"/>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>

 <!--EDIT-->
 <rule name="Redirect to HTTP">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON"/>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have tried this but the problem is that, my pages are redirected to HTTPS and when it passed to mypage.php page it still remains as HTTPS, I need something that will make it redirect back to HTTP or make it stay as HTTP rather than HTTPS.

Comment: Please note the php file linked from my html is like: `<form action="../mypage.php" method="get">`

Comment: I edited the answer to add another rule for redirecting php pages to http: when the link is https:. But in your comment you say that the link is ../mypage.php, so my suggestion would be to have your form action be a full url like `http://www.domain.com/mypage.php`. But if you can't do that then this extra rule should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you but it will not work, it says "The page isn’t redirecting properly". I tried to add full URL but it gives security warning when passing form HTTPS to HTTP page when I click submit button.

Comment: Hum I tried the rules on my own site and they work perfectly. Are you sure you don't have another redirect in the code somewhere? Try emptying your cache. Also, when you put the full URL did you use www? Your first rule could interfere if you didn't.