# Root page has forced redirect to http protocol or how to exclude root page from redirection to https

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have access to IIS application and I do not know who created and deployed it. But I need to make this app work through **https** protocol. I've created let's encrypt certificate and applied it to the site. If I follow some URL like: `https://example.com/aboutus` and so on - it works as expected. But when I try to access `https://example.com`, it forcibly redirects me to `http://example.com`. Then, when I access other pages through navigation menu, they are `http://example.com/about_us` and so on, except a few pages which are forcibly redirected to `https`, such as `https://example.com/sign_up` and `sign_in`.

If I apply the following rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

all pages are being redirected, but the main page could not be loaded because of hard-coded redirect:

[image]

I don't know if it hard-coded somewhere or no. But at the moment I want to redirect everything except the main page to **https**. How could I do it?

Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333017/10854998) does not work in my case

This does not work also:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
         <add input="{URL}" pattern="example\.com\/.+" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: "it forcibly redirects me to http://example.com" clearly comes from the web application itself not IIS (you can use FRT to analyze further https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules). The best solution is to ask the developers of that web app how to stop its internal redirection to HTTP (maybe there is already a setting in configuration system).

Comment: Thank you for your advice with FRT. It helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following Lex Li's advice about using FRT, I've found out URL Rewrite module works with relative paths. For example, `http://example.com/about_us` was just `/about_us` and because of this my `pattern="example\.com\/.+"` did not work.

The following rule works as expected:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
           <add input="{URL}" pattern="\/.+" />
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
       </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

All pages with `http` protocol which relative pates start with `/` and have at least one symbol behind it, should be redirected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this rule, use {HTTP_HOST} variable to match the root page, and then negate it through the [negate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-pattern-properties) attribute.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS except root page" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^http://example.com$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
       </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```